# Auth0: NoSuchMethodError while authentication

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, auth0, grails3

The NoSuchMethodError happens when i make a request to secured resource.

Project based on Grails 3.2.5 which based on Spring Boot 1.4.4

AppConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "auth0", value = "clientSecret")
class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value('${auth0.issuer}')
    private String issuer
    @Value('${auth0.audience}')
    private String audience
    @Value('${auth0.clientId}')
    private String clientId
    @Value('${auth0.clientSecret}')
    private String secret

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer.forHS256(audience, issuer, secret.getBytes())
                .configure(http)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dbconsole/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ACCOUNT_MANAGER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }
}
```

clientId, secret, audience and other configuration parameters taken from my auth0 account.

build.gradle part:

```
compile 'com.auth0:auth0:1.+'
compile 'com.auth0:auth0-spring-security-api:1.+'
compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.+'
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.auth0.jwt.JWT.require(Lcom/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm;)Lcom/auth0/jwt/JWTVerifier$Verification;
at com.auth0.spring.security.api.JwtAuthenticationProvider.providerForHS256(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:96)
at com.auth0.spring.security.api.JwtAuthenticationProvider.jwtVerifier(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:67)
at com.auth0.spring.security.api.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:57)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:354)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can share a demo project which can help to reproduce this bug.

Comment: Dependencies should be missing..recheck

Comment: @Akshay according to [this sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample/blob/v1/pom.xml) all dependencies are okey

Comment: Try changing compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.+' to compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.1.0'

Comment: unfortunately the same result

Comment: This error most likely means that you are using the wrong version of a library - Spring expects one version, but you are using a different version which does not have the expected method.

Comment: @Jesper hm.. i think you're right, but i haven't recommendations from Auth0 for spring version.. i hope that auth0 support will see this post

Comment: Maybe you should ask at https://support.auth0.com/ instead of hoping they will see your question on StackOverflow...

Comment: i made it in the same time with this post. Have no answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted `compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.+'` and the project imported older version of this library and then project has been compiled.